# Custom sorting in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting

I have to implement sorting functionality in my app. Kindly consider the following logics.

I want to sort the array RangeClass objects based on the given input (say 50).

```
class RangeClass:NSObject {
    var start:Int64!
    var end:Int64!

    convenience init(s:Int64,e:Int64) {
        self.init()
        self.start = s
        self.end = e

    }


    var test1 = RangeClass(s: 50, e: 62) // 50 is in the range
    var test2 = RangeClass(s: 12, e: 26) // 50 is not in the range
    var test3 = RangeClass(s: 78, e: 89) // 50 is not in the range
    var test4 = RangeClass(s: 35, e: 89) // 50 is in the range
    var test5 = RangeClass(s: 11, e: 74) // 50 is in the range
    var test6 = RangeClass(s: 26, e: 62) // 50 is in the range

    var testArr:NSArray=[test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6]

    testArr[0]
    testArr[0]


    print(testArr)


    testArr.sortedArrayUsingComparator { (
         testA, testB) -> NSComparisonResult in

    let p1 = testA as! RangeClass
    let p2 = testB as! RangeClass
    // check whether both are in the range
    if p1.start > 50 && p1.end < 50 && p2.start > 50 && p2.end < 50
    {

        if (p1.start > p2.start) {
            return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending;
        }

    }else if (p1.start > 50 && p1.end < 50){
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }else if (p2.start > 50 && p2.end < 50){
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }else{
        if (p1.start > p2.start) {
            return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to the output like

> test5,test6,test4,test1,test2,test3

ie Objects which are in the Range should come first and which are not is the range joins last.

Comment: You should explain your logic with words. But the first `if` test, aren't `<` et `>` inverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this algorithm catches all cases but at least that one in the question.

```
let refNum : Int64 = 50

let sortedArray = testArr.sort { (rangeA, rangeB) -> Bool in
  let a = (rangeA.start...rangeA.end).contains(refNum)
  let b = (rangeB.start...rangeB.end).contains(refNum)

  switch (a, b) {
  case (true, true), (false, false) : return rangeA.start < rangeB.start
  case (true, false) : return true
  case (false, true) : return false
  }
}

print(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create swift array like this:

```
var testArr = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6]
```

And create some sorted functioin. In your case it can be something like this:

```
func sortRangesToContainValue(firstItem: RangeClass, secondItem: RangeClass) -> Bool {
    switch value {
    case firstItem.start...firstItem.end:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Here `value` is `let value: Int64 = 50`

And final step is call `sortInPlace` method of your array:

```
testArr.sortInPlace(sortRangesToContainValue)
```

It sorts the array so as you wish. To add a new sorting options, you can simply change the method or add a new which will probably use both input parameters.

Comment: Thanks Alex, its working. I got 4 objects ( in Range) and 2 objects (outside Rage). I need to add one more sorting like sort the 4 objects  ( in the range ) and 2 (outside Range)  objects ascending order based on start